# Stop javascript function after it's already been called in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

is there a way to stop a javascript function from continuing to execute after it's been called in the browser?

For example, if a function is called on load of the page, but if I do a

```
$(window).resize(function(){});
```

and the width of the window goes below 768 pixels, I no longer want this function executing. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i mean.. you can unbind it, but i suspect there's more to your question than that.

Comment: you could check at the start of the resize function what the width is, if it is below 768px don't process the rest of your function. Or you could do as @Kevin B suggested, and remove the eventhandler from the resize event.

Comment: `if (window.innerWidth < 768) return;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function to only be able to run once, you could do something like this:

```js
function once(func) {
  var res = null,
      called = false,
      func = func.bind(func);
  return function() {
    if (called) return res;
    else {
      called = true;
      res = func.apply(this, arguments);
      func = null;
    }
  }
}
var dosomething = once(function() {
  alert('this only happens once');
});
```

```html
<button onclick="dosomething()">once</button>
```